Accessing LinkedIn Profile Data (LinkedIn API)
We are building an app, where experts create their profile (like a job board). For that, we would like to have a feature to "Import LinkedIn Profile".
Users will sign in with LinkedIn, and we will import their experience, education, skills, and .etc from their LinkedIn profile.
Right now, we only have "Login with LinkedIn" working properly, without any issues. And we are accessing from this API: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo
But we can't access the full profile of the user.
Looks like we need more permission.
We are stuck, because of confusing documentation of the LinkedIn.

What API do we get that full profile information we are looking for?
What permissions do we need?
How to get those permissions? Do we have to apply to any LinkedIn program to get access?

In the "Products" tab of the LinkedIn app, there are numerous products such as "Advertising API", "Lead Sync API" and .etc, but none of them seem like the one we are looking for.
